# How can I read a file from the application server from Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have been asked to write code in Oracle Forms that reads data from a file in the "middleware" (application server) rather than on the client side.  The purpose is to hold an encryption key in a place where people won't stumble upon it.

I know I can use TEXT_IO package to read a file on the client side, but is there something similar to read files on the other side?

Version details:

> Forms [32 Bit] Version 10.1.2.3.0 (Production) Oracle Toolkit Version
>   10.1.2.0.2 (Production) PL/SQL Version 10.1.0.5.0 (Production) Oracle Procedure Builder V10.1.2.3.0 - Production PL/SQL Editor (c) WinMain
>   Software (www.winmain.com), v1.0 (Production) Oracle Query Builder
>   10.1.2.3.0 - Production Oracle Virtual Graphics System Version 10.1.2.0.2 (Production) Oracle Tools GUI Utilities Version 10.1.2.0.2 (Production) Oracle Multimedia Version 10.1.2.0.2 (Production) Oracle
>   Tools Integration Version 10.1.2.0.2 (Production) Oracle Tools Common
>   Area Version 10.1.2.0.2 Oracle CORE       10.1.0.5.0
>   Production   SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Thu Nov 22
>   19:44:05 2012 Copyright (c) 1982, 2006, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.
>   Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release
>   11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining and Real
>   Application Testing options

Comment: The forms 10g will be on the server. The file exists in the same server or are you trying to read a file from another server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TEXT_IO reads files from directories *local to the Forms runtime*. In client/server mode that would be our desktop PC but in web-delivered Forms that is the app server.

So TEXT_IO is actually the function you need to use in the scenario you describe.

What TEXT_IO can't do is read or write to files on the desktop PC.  That's the reason why Oracle added [the Webutils library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/webutil-090641.html), to provide the client-side functionality which no longer works in n-tier architectures.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I am misunderstanding your question but you can use `TEXT_IO` itself to read and write files in the "App Server". I work on Oracle Forms 10g, and below is the text right from the Forms Online Help document.

---

**About the TEXT_IO**

Package Description The `TEXT_IO` Package contains constructs that provide ways to write and read information to and from files. There are several procedures and functions available in Text_IO, falling into the following categories:

**Usage Notes**

1. Text_IO ***operates on the application server machine, not the client***.
2. Some of the text_io functions ( put, putf, put_line and new_line ) have overloaded versions which do not take a file (file_type) argument as the first parameter. In 6i and earlier versions, these functions were not operational unless you were working in debug mode, in which case they wrote to the Debug Console. In Oracle Forms, because there is a different debugger which has no console, these versions of these Built-ins have no effect at all. These Built-ins are for backwards compatibility and will be removed in a future release.
3. For TEXT_IO package to work with non-ASCII file names, the NLS_LANG must match the encoding of the platform. e.g. JA16SJIS for Windows Japanese.

---

To be able to read and write files on the Client machine you will have to use **WebUtil CLIENT_TEXT_IO**.

Just refer to the Forms Developer Help Menu > Online Help and search for the terms `TEXT_IO` and `CLIENT_TEXT_IO` and you will see the details.

---

However as documented by Oracle the below must be kept in mind-

> Many Forms applications utilize Text_IO to read and write data from
>   the file system. When moving your Forms application to the Web,
>   Text_IO works in exactly the same manner as client/server. However,
>   you must now remember that your application is running on the
>   application server and not the client machine.

Here's a quick [example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/howto-textio-092797.html).